# Did Bilbo see Gandalf in between The Hobbit and The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, books, the-hobbit

I know that in Jackson's *Fellowship of the Ring* Bilbo greets Gandalf as an old friend that he hasn't seen for many years. That implies that it's the first meeting between the pair since Bilbo returned from his adventures at the end of *The Hobbit*.

In the books there is no such meeting. Biblo simply gives Gandalf a hand loading the fireworks off the cart and then later has a discussion with Gandalf about meaning to follow through with his plan.

> At Bilbo's front door the old man began to unload: there were great bundles of fireworks of all sorts and shapes...When the old man, helped by Bilbo and some dwarves, had finished unloading, Bilbo gave a few pennies away...
>   <sub>*(Fellowship of the Ring, Chapter 1, A Long-Expected Party)*.</sub>

There's no indication in that snippet of whether this is the first time Bilbo has seen in many years.

**Did Bilbo see Gandalf between the end of *The Hobbit* and the meeting above in *The Lord of the Rings*?**

I'm interested in an answer based on the books. I'm only going off the movies since I don't have a copy of *The Hobbit* on me.

Comment: @JasonBaker. Yes, big crossover, I admit. Though G could have visited Hobbiton without visiting Bilbo.

Comment: Not untrue, but one is certainly a subset of the other

Comment: @JasonBaker Fair nough. :)